# Invariant violation when using react apollo hooks alongside query components

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm beginning our migration from Apollo Client 2.x to 3.x beta, and I'm having trouble using both the apollo hooks and the now deprecated query/mutation components.

I'm using the packages:

```
@apollo/client: 3.0.0-beta.4
@apollo/react-components: 3.1.3
```

Using the apollo hooks works fine in this case, but using the query component, I get the following error:

> Invariant Violation
>       Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option.
>       Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

I've created a codesandbox that shows this issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-9p9ym

I think the issue is with the source of the `ApolloProvider` I'm using, but not sure which package to get that from if I want to use the new beta, while still using the query components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should import `ApolloProvider` from the same package as the component or hook that's using it. That's because the context provided by `ApolloProvider` needs to be the same as the context being used by the component or hook. if you use different packages, the context object will be different.

The `react-apollo` package exports all three: `ApolloProvider`, `Query` and `useQuery`. If you use that package, you can use the `ApolloProvider` with both `Query` and `useQuery`. `@apollo/client`, however, only exports `ApolloProvider` and `useQuery`. That's because the `graphql` HOC and the render prop components have been deprecated. If you insist on using both `Query` and `useQuery`, you have to import `Query` from another package, like `@apollo/react-components` and add its `ApolloProvider` as well:

```
import {
  ApolloProvider as ApolloProvider2,
  Query,
} from '@apollo/react-components'
import {
  ApolloProvider,
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  useQuery,
  gql,
} from '@apollo/client'

<ApolloProvider2 client={client}>
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App/>
  </ApolloProvider>
</ApolloProvider2>
```

Notice that you can import `gql` directly from `apollo@client` as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I had thought that the deprecation would have still meant they were compatible with the same Provider until they were removed, but I see that's not the case. Thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind the incompatibility comes from the fact you're using different packages, because of the way context works. You'd have the same issue using, for example, two different redux packages that each required a context provider.